# Cannot recognize Text when using Firebase_ml_vision kit from camera

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

Im trying to build an app that uses the Text Recognition that comes with the Firebase_ml_vision package. When i use the Firebase.VisionImage.fromFile(pickedImage) and i download a picture from the internet with text it works perfectly, but when i try to use an image taken with my iPhone Xr camera it does not read the text decently. The output is similar to this:

flutter: 2000
AADAT4A
flutter: 2000
AADAT4A
flutter: 20000
flutter: 03012
flutter: 2000

this happens when i try to print blocks.text lines or elements.

Does anyone have an ideia how to implement this?

I used this code: (its not all the code but the necessary)

```
File pickedImage;

List<String> words = [];

Future pickImage() async {
    var tempStore =
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); //gallery here
    setState(() {
      pickedImage = tempStore;
      isImageLoaded = true;
    });
  }

    Future pickCameraImage() async {
        var tempStore =
            await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera); //camera here
        setState(() {
          pickedImage = tempStore;
          isImageLoaded = true;
        });
      }

    Future readText() async {
        FirebaseVisionImage ourImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(pickedImage);
        TextRecognizer recognizeText = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
        VisionText readText = await recognizeText.processImage(ourImage);

    for (TextBlock block in readText.blocks) {
//      final Rect boundingBox = block.boundingBox;
//      final List<Offset> cornerPoints = block.cornerPoints;
//      final String text = block.text;
//      final List<RecognizedLanguage> languages = block.recognizedLanguages;

      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        print(block.text);
        for (TextElement word in line.elements) {
          words.add(word.text);
        }
      }
    } isTextLoaded = true;
  }
```

In the Ui part:

(...)

```
RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Pick an Image'),
            onPressed: pickImage,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Pick a Camera Image'),
            onPressed: pickCameraImage,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Read Text'),
            onPressed: readText,
          ),
```

(...)

I do not have any errors. Anyone with more experience can help me? Thank you